# Encourage 'Audio' beta site participation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Could we make it policy to push people towards [Audio](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66599/audio)
 *'Proposed Q&A site for electronic musicians, DJs, and professionals using DAWs'* - not newbies who may just need an answer to the wrong topic 'right now' but more established members - in order to ease the separation of 'pure' sound design from questions on DAWs etc.

There have been a few attempts to get this type of forum going, but this one (Sound Design) has not had a happy time being merged, Audio-Video Production has already just become [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com) & 'Music' has become [Musical Practice & Performance](http://music.stackexchange.com) - leaving a gap for 'pro-audio'.

It would then be up to that site whether to accept 'How do I make this snare sound?', 'which Mic to use for drum overheads?' -type questions, or 'Which is a good DAW for Mac? (which I personally down-voted ;)

Further subdivision might come later, but for now at least, I feel we do need one site on SE to be a suitable repository for this question type; & this looks like the best we have right now.

My personal area is music for film, so even with the new proposal I'll still be sitting between stools, but it does feel like this area is needed to broaden SE's spectrum.
I wouldn't be so hopeful that a 'music for film' forum would ever see the light of day ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is already on topic here and I don't think a new proposal is needed. This was originally intended to cover all the audio side of avp which covered everything sound would cover. There has just been a lot of scope fighting between avp members and social sound design members so we are a bit spilt personality at the moment.

Overall, I think the two areas are two similar to support two separate sites though. I'd be active on the audio site if it happens but I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Having spent most of the day reading the meta history, I didn't get the impression 'pro-audio' was at all welcome here - not for all, but certainly by a vociferous few.. but I am not in any position to play god-mod to a well-established user-base, whatever its political differences. It would seem easier to separate the disciplines rather than fight over them.

Comment: To qualify that a little further - would it not be better overall if users with specific requirements could have those requirements met, rather than come to blows over definitions, eventually leading to a tumbleweed.com ?

Comment: @Tetsujin - there in lies the problem though, it's only a vocal few that don't like them and most of those users already left.  The site was merged because, as far as I know, the feeling was that the original scope of SSD was too narrow, but some of community that was merged in didn't like that and have fought it tooth and nail.  Pretty much all of the original AVP community want a broader scope like what they had before and even some of the SSD crowd haven't been vocal opponents to it.  I don't think that sub-divided sites will have enough content to survive.

Comment: right now, though, sound design is almost down to tumbleweed - & I don't have sufficient history here to really have an opinion over the merge, I'm a relative newbie. imho, though, a 'pro-audio' SE would be a welcome addition, let this structure stand or fall on its own merits, rather than 'pollute' it with DAW questions. Not that pure DAW would suit my particular needs, but I'm trying to think outside my own personal structure, to a broader, yet acceptable, scope.

Comment: @Tetsujin, but this site _is_ the 'pro-audio' SE.  Except for the inclusion of Video back on AVP, it was and has been the pro-audio SE.  When SSD merged with the audio portion of AVP, it did not cease to be a pro-audio SE.

Comment: Or put another way, if this isn't the pro-audio SE, then I'm on the wrong site, because 90+% of my knowledge and experience is live sound and recording audio for video and we have a good number of other high rep users who I think that might be the case for as well.  What we do need to figure out is scoping statement and possibly a rename to make it more clear to people what the site is about so that we draw in the intended audience.  Right now, the site is ambiguous, even to those of us who are the biggest participants.  Don't let being relatively new get in the way of speaking up either.

Comment: Well, as they say, "If the scope fits. wear it" ;-) I'm fine with it if this *is* pro-audio too; my concern was due to the rather high noise-level on the Meta, when I started reading back through the history. If the dust has truly settled on that, then I see no reason to fire up a new group if the topic is covered in here.

Comment: I think the FAQ needs to be updated if this site welcomes pro-audio questions. The current "What topics can I ask about here" is too vague, especially considering the merge of SSD and AVP went so poorly. Like Tetsujin, meta gives the impression that anything out of film sound design is contentious.